# Interesting Eclipse JavaDoc commenter error

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

So when I was working on a lab for my class, I used the ALT+SHIFT+J Eclipse shortcut to auto generate Javadoc comments for my functions. Here are some examples where I had no problem:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
 /**
 * Mutator method for setting processorSpeed.
 *
 * @param newProcessorSpeed Updated processor speed value
 */
 public void setProcessorSpeed(double newProcessorSpeed)
 {
 processorSpeed = newProcessorSpeed;
 }


 // ----------------------------------------------------------
 /**
 * Returns value of computer power
 *
 * @return numcores * processorSpeed
 */
 public double computePower()
 {
 double temp = numcores * processorSpeed;
 return temp;
 }
```

However, when I tried to do the same shortcut for this function:

```
public String toString()
 {
 String temp =
 processor + ", " + String.valueOf(numcores) + " cores at "
 + String.valueOf(processorSpeed) + "GHz";
 return temp;
 }
```

All I get is:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
 public String toString()
 {
 String temp =
 processor + ", " + String.valueOf(numcores) + " cores at "
 + String.valueOf(processorSpeed) + "GHz";
 return temp;
 }
```

Just thought it was an interesting error. Curious as to what makes Eclipse treat the toString function differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are overwriting the method a non-javadoc comment is generated. Every Java object inherits from `Object` and `Object` defines a `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the behavior I get. Instead, I get a block comment that starts `/* (non-Javadoc)`. This is because toString() is an inherited function and that's the behavior that the auto-doc shortcut invokes in my setup. Yours is obviously set up differently.

You can set up any template you like for various contexts by going to **Window -> Settings** and then navigating to **Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates**. The docs for the variables you can use in a template can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/codestyle/ref-preferences-code-templates.htm). The template for comments to overriding methods in my setup is:

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * ${see_to_overridden}
 */
```